# blogger <b:template-skin> error bX-d55p58

Tags: html, css, xml, blogger

My problem is in blogger template design
When I add this tag `<b:template-skin>` this error message appear to me
[image: blogger error message]

Is there any solution?

Comment: What is the content of `<b:template-skin>` can you show the code!

Comment: Nothing.
as soon as I add it and click save the error get popup
I write it as this 

`<b:template-skin></b:template-skin>`
or 

`<b:template-skin>//<![CDATA[`

`//]]></b:template-skin>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to define layout version by adding attribute `b:layoutsVersion='3'` to html tage like the following

```
<html b:css='false' b:layoutsVersion='3' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<b:template-skin></b:template-skin> or <b:template-skin>//<![CDATA[ //]]></b:template-skin> 
<html b:css='false' b:layoutsVersion='3' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
```

Comment: A good answer, but it should also include a short explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
or // http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>

<b:template-skin></b:template-skin> or <b:template-skin>//<![CDATA[ //]]></b:template-skin> 
<html b:css='false' b:layoutsVersion='3' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='h
```

Comment: Please edit your existing answer instead of adding a new one

Answer (score 0):

```
<html b:css='false' b:layoutsVersion='3'>
```

```html
Eg:
<html b:css='false' b:layoutsVersion='3' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>

Note: <b:template-skin> can't be used in b:layoutsVersion 1.
```

Comment: This is rather a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it